# Can I make a DNS query directly from the browser?

Tags: javascript, dns, frontend

I would like to build a simple web app that asks the user for a domain, performs an DNS query on it, and returns the results.

It's fairly simple to achieve this with a server, but I wonder if this is possible without using a server at all - simply making the NS query using JS from the browser.

I'm looking for a full query, not just IP - all the CNAMES and text fields as well.

I've found the [`dns.resolve()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/dns/resolve) API, but it's only supported in Firefox for some reason.

**Is there a globally available API or library to make NS queries from the browser?**